# jQuery Unable to remove multiple neighboring elements on AJAX Success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out why I am unable to remove multiple neighboring elements on a successful ajax DELETE. When I had `$(".file-preview").filter("a[href='" + fileLink + "']").remove();` by itself in the code below, I was able to remove the first link and when I add `$(".remove-file").data("file-link", fileLink).remove();` after it, it breaks the first `.remove()` statement and removes all of the present `.remove-file` disregarding the value being passed to the `data-file-link` attribute in the link.

1) Why would the first remove be broken by this second remove?

2) Is there a better approach to what I'm trying to achieve which is to remove both neighboring elements on the click of `.remove-file`?

**Here is an example of what the HTML looks like:**

```
<div class="file-section>
    <div class=" file-preview ">
    <a href="https://test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-01-30/screen-shot-2017-01-08-at-12.23.39-pm.png ">https://test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-01-30/screen-shot-2017-01-08-at-12.23.39-pm.png</a>
    <a href="# " class="remove-file " data-file-link="https://test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-01-30/screen-shot-2017-01-08-at-12.23.39-pm.png "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class=" file-preview ">
    <a href="https://test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-01-30/screen-shot-2017-01-08-at-12.23.39-pm.png ">https://test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-01-30/screen-shot-2017-01-08-at-12.23.39-pm.png</a>
    <a href="# " class="remove-file " data-file-link="https://test-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2017-01-30/screen-shot-2017-01-08-at-12.23.39-pm.png "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $(document).on('click', '.remove-file', function(){
        console.log('Delete Triggered');
        var fileLink = $(this).data('file-link');

        function pathExtract(url){
            var fullUrl = url;
            var delimiter = '/';
            var start = 3;
            var tokens = fullUrl.split(delimiter).slice(start);
            var path = tokens.join(delimiter);
            return path;  
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/app/sign?' + $.param({"file": pathExtract(fileLink)}),
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(){
                console.log('This is the file link ' + fileLink);
                $(".file-preview").filter("a[href='" + fileLink + "']").remove();
                $(".remove-file").data("file-link", fileLink).remove();
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log('error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$(".remove-file").remove()` removes all elements with that class. Calling `.data()` doesn't change that. Why are you adding data to an element you're going to remove, anyway?

Comment: Are you assuming that `$(".remove-file").data("file-link", fileLink)` filters the selection to just those elements with that data value? `data()` isn't a filter, when you call it with two arguments it assigns the data.

Comment: When you do 'data('dataName', value) you're setting a value to 'data' field of this element... If you want to delete the element with these fileLink , you must find like ('.file-link[data-file-link=' + fileLink + ').remove() or something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.data("file-link", fileLink)` isn't a filter, it sets the data of the elements selected. It simply returns the same collection it was called on, so when you call `.remove()` on the result it removes all the elements with the `remove-file` class.

If you want to remove just the elements with that data value, use `.filter()`:

```
$(".remove-file").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("file-link") == fileLink;
}).remove();
```

This code:

```
$(".file-preview").filter("a[href='" + fileLink + "']").remove();
```

doesn't work because the `a` element is inside the `.file-preview` DIV, but `.filter()` tests if the element itself matches the filter. You should write:

```
$(".file-preview:has(a[href='" + fileLink + "'])").remove();
```

to test the contents.

Comment: thank you for your answer and catching my oversight on using `.data` instead of `filter`. Im hoping to remove both `.remove-file` and `.file-preview` on the click of `.remove-file`, but it appears that these answers only remove the `.remove-file` element and leaves `.file-preview` in place. Any solution that will remove both after the click on `.remove-file`?

Comment: I didn't notice that the `href` filter was on a different class.

Comment: `file-preview` is the class of the `div`, but `href` is on the `a` inside it. Why are you calling `.filter()` on the `div`?

Comment: Thank you for correcting my main filter above to allow me to remove both elements included in the div.